# Placing a vector of objects as predictors in a model.matrix

Tags: r

I have the following vector with the charater letters representing each one a data frame of numbers

```
PreVar<-unique(c(list.ABC))

PreVar

[1] "Dxg"    "Dxu8"   "Dxu10"  "Cont2"  "Cont3"  "Cont41" "Cont42" "Cont44" "Cont52"  
"Cont62"
```

I would like to place the 10 PreVar objects (without quotation marks) in the expression below with the + sign between them as predictors of the model.matrix below.

```
X <- model.matrix(z[2:length(z)] ~        )[,-1]
```

Is there a any other way to do it besides manually imputing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to use [?paste](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) and [?as.formula](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/formula.html).  Consider:

```
PreVar <- c("Dxg", "Dxu8", "Dxu10", "Cont2", "Cont3", "Cont41", "Cont42", 
            "Cont44", "Cont52", "Cont62")
pastevar <- paste(c("z[2:length(z)] ~", paste(PreVar, collapse=" + ")))
as.formula(pastevar)
z[2:length(z)] ~ Dxg + Dxu8 + Dxu10 + Cont2 + Cont3 + Cont41 + 
    Cont42 + Cont44 + Cont52 + Cont62
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, however the Cont series should read Cont[[2]], Cont[[3]],... as the digit is the location. Did not mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
X <- model.matrix(z[2:length(z)] ~ .       , data = z)[,-1]
```

I think you just need a period after ~, that way you don't have to deal with any handling of names.